# arrastrar un elemento html y poder soltarlo en medio de otros elementos y no al final del contenedor

Tags: javascript

Buen dia a todos, requiero ayuda para poder arrastrar un elemento y soltarlo en medio de otros elementos y no tener que agregarlos siempre al final de la lista de nodos.

Como lo imagine hacer es que el elemento contenedor que permite el drop tendrá otros elementos hijos;

mi idea era captar el id del ultimo elemento hijo sobre el cual se paso el que se esta arrastrando antes de soltarlo y
con ese ID saber antes de que nodo debo agregarlo con insetBefore(), asi que les coloque a todos los elementos en ondragover(event, this.id) pero no me toma ningun ID.

¿como puedo tomar el ID del ultimo elemento sobre el que se paso antes de soltarlo en el contenedor ?

```js
function dragStart(event) {
  event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target.id);
}
function dentro(event, id){
  event.preventDefault();
  event.dataTransfer.setData("sobre", id);
}
function soltar(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  var id = event.dataTransfer.getData("sobre");
  var nodoDrop = document.getElementById(data);
  //var antesDe = document.getElementById(id);

  document.getElementById("container").appendChild(nodoDrop);
  alert(id); //el id sobre el cual se solto o se poso por ultima vez
  //document.getElementById("container").insertBefore(nodoDrop,antesDe);
}
```

```html
<div style="border:1px solid black;" >
  <p id="p1" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" ondragover="dentro(event,this.id)">parrafo1</p>
  <p id="p2" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" ondragover="dentro(event,this.id)">parrafo2</p>
  <p id="p3" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" ondragover="dentro(event,this.id)">parrafo3</p>
  <button id="btn1" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" ondragover="dentro(event,this.id)">btn1</button>
</div>
<br>
<div id="container" style="border:1px solid blue;" ondrop="soltar(event)" ondragover="dentro(event,this.id)"><p> texto fijo </p>
   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es posible hacerlo de esa manera, mientras estas arrastrando el evento se bloquea y no puedes ocupar event.dataTransfer. Esto lo puedes comprobar si haces

```
function dentro(event, id){
  event.preventDefault();
  event.dataTransfer.setData("sobre", id);
  console.log(event.dataTransfer.getData("sobre")):
}
```

Metes un dato y lo lees enseguida. La consola te arrojará algo en blanco

La solución simple es una variable global, tambien ocupar el evento ondragenter
en vez de ondragover, el primero se ejecuta una vez cuando entra al elemento, en cambio, el segundo se ejecuta varias veces mientras estes dentro del elemento

```js
var target;
function dragStart(event) {
  event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target.id);
}
function dentro(event, id){
  event.preventDefault();
    target = id;
}
function sobre(event, id){
  event.preventDefault();
}
function soltar(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  var id = target;
  var nodoDrop = document.getElementById(data);
  //var antesDe = document.getElementById(id);

  document.getElementById("container").appendChild(nodoDrop);
  console.log(id); //el id sobre el cual se solto o se poso por ultima vez
  //
}
```

```html
<div style="border:1px solid black;" >
  <p id="p1" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" ondragenter="dentro(event,this.id)">parrafo1</p>
  <p id="p2" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" ondragenter="dentro(event,this.id)">parrafo2</p>
  <p id="p3" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" ondragenter="dentro(event,this.id)">parrafo3</p>
  <button id="btn1" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" ondragenter="dentro(event,this.id)">btn1</button>
</div>
<br>
<div id="container" style="border:1px solid blue;" ondrop="soltar(event)" ondragover="sobre(event,this.id)"><p> texto fijo </p>
   
</div>
```